# docker0 interface missing on osx

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker

On OSX I followed the installation instructions of boot2docker and am able to build and run Debian containers. However, the documentation states that the host (osx) should have a `docker0` interface, binding the container with the host.
However:
`$ ifconfig docker0
ifconfig: interface docker0 does not exist`

How do I create the docker0 interface on osx?
My goal is to communicate with an open db port on the host machine.

Comment: I'm wondering what this interface name|alias even is.  It doesn't come with boot2docker.  A few blogs mention it and use it to automate things.  For example, configuring etcd or redis automatically because you can find the public ip?  I'm lost.  I thought containers have ports and the host would have the IP.

Comment: For people who are using docker for MAC natively, It seems on Docker for Mac it's normal that docker0 doesn't exist. That interface would be within the VM that's running the Docker daemon, not MacOS directly https://acloud.guru/forums/docker-fundamentals/discussion/-LBvhNk6pmRmkwSRSrdS/No%20%22Docker0%22%20shown%20for%20ifconfig%20on%20Mac

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22753

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `boot2docker ssh` to login your virtual machine first. 
Boot2docker install virtualbox in your osx and boot a debian distribution on it. And your docker is installed in your virtual machine.

Comment: this gets me into the VM where docker0 is indeed found, but how do I connect to a port on the host? `telnet 172.17.42.1 port` doesn't seem to work

Comment: 172.17.42.1 is a private ip. and this interface is to communicate with your container. You cannot connect a private ip on a host.

Comment: `boot2docker` is DEPRECATED long ago.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to directly access the containers IP (172.17.0.0/16) which you can retrieve by typing `docker inspect <container_id>`.

You must have to add the routes from the boot2docker VM by typing `sudo route -n add 172.17.0.0/16 $(boot2docker ip)`

Then your containers are directly available on your host